# How to create a function that checks for a substring in a linked table using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I need to create a column with True or False in query.

```
class Orders(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'orders'

    id = Column(INTEGER, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)      
    created_at = Column(INTEGER, default=time_now)
    come_column = Column(TEXT)

    operations = relationship('Operations', backref='operations', passive_deletes=True)

class Operations(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'operations'

    id = Column(INTEGER, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)  
    title = Column(TEXT)
    amount = Column(INTEGER)                                                    
    price = Column(FLOAT) 
    order_id = Column(INTEGER, ForeignKey(orders.id))  

# I need something like that:
query = session.query(Orders, any(['substring' in op.title for op in Orders.operations]))
result = query.all()
```

I have no idea how this can be done. Give me the direction, please!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

An inner join and a where clause should do what you want :

```python
q = ( 
    session.query(Orders)
           .join(Orders.operations)
           # ilike is case insensitive, use like if case matters to you 
           .filter(Operation.title.ilike("%substring%")
)
```

The generated SQL :

```sql
SELECT
    [...]
FROM
    orders
INNER JOIN operations ON
    orders.id = operations.order_id
WHERE
    lower(operations.title) LIKE lower('%substring%')
```